# how to read file contents using axios and a file URL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, readfile

I want to read the file contents from text files, whose URLs I'll be passing into axios.

What I want to achieve basically is to read data from text files and store the data in a string variable.

I tried to use 'response.on('data', chunk=>{..})' but it didn't work in axios.

My code is like this

```
axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: file,
        responseType: 'stream'
      })
        .then(function (response) {

        //What to do here? Something to do with response.data?
```

});

Comment: Are the files hosted locally with your app or are they remote? If the former, wouldn't you just use [`fsPromises.readFile()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_readfile_path_options) or similar? If the latter, I'd recommend omitting the `responseType` and let Axios return plain text

Comment: Files are hosted on some server which gives me direct links to the files

For example: https://x0.at/xyz.txt

Comment: It's all on https://github.com/axios/axios

Comment: Are the files particularly large? Is there a reason you're using `responseType: 'stream'`?

Comment: @Phil The files will not be more than 4mb, which is why your suggestion works perfectly for me. Thanks a lot!